# Using delegateCall without knowing the called contract's address

Tags: addresses, delegatecall

I am fairly new to Solidity and slowly starting to grasp its ecosystem :-)
I have a question about using delegateCall: How do I ensure that I call exactly the contract I want to call?

Let's assume I have contract A (in file A.sol) and contract B (in file B.sol). I deploy both contracts.
In A, I would like to use delegateCall to use a function in B. Is this possible without knowing the address of B? If so how do I ensure that I do call **my** contract B and not any other contract with the exact same name?

I hope I state the problem with the correct terms.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to interact with a contract be it between multiple on-chain contracts or a javascript client and an on-chain contract you do need the address of the contract you're trying to interact with.